# Async task not null for do inbackground but null in on post execute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hi I am getting a null pointer exception and I am not sure why.

I am calling my database from do in background and I tested the size of the array "results" and it is not null.

but then when I go to use the results in onpostexecute I am getting a null pointer exception:

This is is my Async Class:

```
public class GetVideoInfoFromDataBase extends AsyncTask {

    // Paginated list of results for alarm database scan
    static PaginatedScanList<AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter> results;

    // The DynamoDB object mapper for accessing DynamoDB.
    private final DynamoDBMapper mapper;

    Context context;
    private AsyncInterface asyncInterface;

    public GetVideoInfoFromDataBase(Context context){
        mapper = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper();
        this.context = context;
        this.asyncInterface = (AsyncInterface) context;

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        System.out.println("The backgrond stuff is working 1");
        DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
        results = mapper.scan(AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter.class, scanExpression);
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Object obj) {

           asyncInterface.response(results);
    }
}
```

So it is the line below that has the null pointer.

```
asyncInterface.response(results);
```

This is my async interface:

```
public interface AsyncInterface {
    void response(PaginatedScanList<AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter> output);
}
```

I this is the main class that calls the async task like this:
public class MainAlarmsFragment extends Fragment implements AsyncInterface {

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_alarms, container, false);
        new GetVideoInfoFromDataBase(context).execute();
    return view;
}

  @Override
    public void response(PaginatedScanList<AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter> output) {

    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: AsyncInterface passing through the constructor is null. Check that code. Nothing to do with the results object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
    public GetVideoInfoFromDataBase(Context context){
        mapper = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper();
        this.context = context;
        this.asyncInterface = (AsyncInterface) context;

    }
```

to this

```
    public GetVideoInfoFromDataBase(Context context,AsyncInterface asyncInterface){
        mapper = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper();
        this.context = context;
        this.asyncInterface = asyncInterface;

    }
```

**UPDATE:** And now execute the asynctask like
**new GetVideoInfoFromDataBase(this,this).execute();** if you are in activity and your activity is implementing **AsyncInterface** interface, else you have to pass **Context** and **AsyncInterface** object references.

Comment: When I change the constructor I am not sure how to run the async task in the main activity. I need two arguments context and asyncinterface. but I am not sure how to pass the interface.

Comment: So I am wondering I have the required overide method for the class. Because I extend async task and overrride response.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much for your help, It is working perfectly! I had never thought about using this as the second argument but it make perfect sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

try to replace your onPostExecute line with below

```
 asyncInterface.response(obj);
```

may be you need to type cast the object obj..

Comment: I get Error:(49, 36) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to PaginatedScanList<AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter>

Comment: you have type cast the obj

Comment: can you share your code so that i can look into code whats the exact issue.?/

Answer (score 1):

```
public GetVideoInfoFromDataBase(Context context,AsyncInterface asyncInterface){
        mapper = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper();
        this.context = context;
        this.asyncInterface = asyncInterface;

    }
```

replace Contructor

Comment: Dear please think 10 times to put comments like this because you have done silly mistake rather than me

Comment: Sorry, It was not meant to be rude I was asking. I have included all my code there. When I change the constructor I am not sure how to run the async task in the main activity.